# Should a user has more than one or one refresh token on its own

Tags: jwt, basic-authentication, refresh-token

I am using JWT and Refresh Tokens for authentication. For now i have one-to-many relationship between user and refresh tokens. I am revoking the refresh token when user logout but not deleting. This is causing more than one refresh tokens per user and this makes a lot of refresh tokens on database. And this causing performance issues. So i am thinking to make one-to-one relationship between user and refresh token. I see no point of user has more than one refresh token(revoked tokens, active tokens vs per user). Do you think is there any reason to keep old refresh tokens for user on refresh token table?
Also do you think i should index the refresh tokens

Comment: `and this makes a lot of refresh tokens on database` ... your first problem is that you are storing your JWT in a database.  Why are you storing them at all?  If you must store, you should be using a cache.

Comment: I dont storing the jwt, i storing refresh tokens

Comment: Same argument.  Why are you storing refresh tokens?

Comment: Isn't that the point? you storing refresh tokens, and finding user id on that refresh tokens, just like sessions

Comment: Nope, you don't store them\

Comment: @emanuelsanga Well, sometimes you _do_ store them, e.g. storing a few JWT in a blacklist cache, but your answer hits the nail on the head by saying that storing every token in a database is not correct usage.

Comment: Oh @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for that.. I think I will have to check on that. I normally store refresh tokens on the client

Comment: I am really sorry, i didn't know JWT means refresh token, i thought it means access token. I am storing my refresh tokens in database. My question is one refresh token per user is okey or i need to make many-to-many relationship because where i read the examples of this auth system they using many-to-many relationship between user and the refresh token. When new refresh token created, old one becoming invalid or when user logout old refresh token is revoked. But i didn't understand to logic of storing more than one refresh token on one user. because it can be done with only one token too.

Comment: @geforce You are missing the entire point of using JWT.  The whole motivation of using JWT is that your user session state exists _outside_ of your application server.  When a user presents an access or refresh token, that JWT by itself ideally contains enough information in order for your server to make a decision about whether to honor or reject it.  A good analogy perhaps more familiar to you would be presenting a passport to customs.  The passport itself contains your roaming credentials.

Comment: Ok, i understand what you are saying. I am doing the same thing with access token. i am using refresh tokens for security. If an attacker get the access token, he/she will only can use until expiration date. When this exp. date came, user needs to use the refresh token to generate a new access token. According to this, how can i define the user based on his/her refresh token to generate new access token if i don't store the refresh tokens in database?

Comment: In that case, you store the refresh token on the users side. Refresh tokens live longer than access tokens

Comment: I am already storing on user side(cookie). But i also have to store them in a database-alike, if i don't what is the point of storing refresh tokens on user side when you cant match them on database and get user Id?

Answer (score 1):

I also use jwt authentication but I don't store the Tokens in the database..

This is the whole point of jwt's, that as long as you use your secret key to create them, your secret key is used to sign them such that the next time a user comes with the token, on decoding you get to know user details and then authorize a given user to given user resources.

What I suggest, remove the tokens from the database and create a method that checks for the tokens validity by decoding the token. This is because, you increase latency by doing a comparison check between a received token and the one in the database while you could simply decode it(I assumed you do comparison just like native token methods). ==> Your database will love this.

Also, have one and only one refresh token. Whenever a new refresh token is made, mark the old one as invalid and issue the new one. First, it's more secure because even if an attacker has attained a refresh token, on issuing a new one, the old one becomes useless.

I do not want to talk about indexing the database with tokens as I believe you are not going to use the database with jwts...

For more information, please read [this](https://curity.io/resources/architect/api-security/jwt-best-practices/)

Comment: i think i didn't make myself clear sorry for that. i dont storing the jwt's in database, i storing the refresh tokens.
"What I suggest, remove the tokens from the database and create a method that checks for the tokens validity by decoding the token. ." 
i am already doing what you say here.
if you storing only one refresh token, how do you mark the old one?when  there is only one?

Comment: Refresh tokens _are_ JWT, and this answer is basically correct +1.

Comment: I am really sorry, i didn't know JWT means refresh token, i thought it means access token. I am storing my refresh tokens in database. My question is one refresh token per user is okey or i need to make many-to-many relationship because where i read the examples of this auth system they using many-to-many relationship between user and the refresh token. When new refresh token created, old one becoming invalid or when user logout old refresh token is revoked. But i didn't understand to logic of storing more than one refresh token on one user because it can be done with only one token too.

Comment: Ahaa, @geforce, JWT for tokens in your scheme are divided into two.... Refresh and Access tokens.

Refresh tokens are used to `refresh` the access tokens(which are the ones that give user access to their authorized objects)...

So both, refresh and access tokens are jwt

Comment: So, is there any downsides of making user and refrestoken relationship one-to-one?

Comment: Schemally no, it is very correct. But it is not that important

Comment: I am not sure it is not that important because it is becoming an performance issue once there is significant online user. There will be lots of unused refresh tokens and also deleting and creating a new refresh token less efficient than updating current refresh token. What do you think?